# Understanding type equality in function signature

Tags: haskell, type-families

In GPipe there is a [function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GPipe-2.2.4/docs/Graphics-GPipe-Texture.html#v:writeTexture2D) for writing to texture:

```
writeTexture2D :: forall ctx b c h w os f m. (ContextHandler ctx, MonadIO m, BufferFormat b, ColorSampleable c, BufferColor (Color c (ColorElement c)) h ~ b, h ~ HostFormat b) => Texture2D os (Format c) -> Level -> StartPos2 -> Size2 -> [h] -> ContextT ctx os m ()
```

I have a problem understanding part of the signature where type equality is used. There is a [tutorial](http://tobbebex.blogspot.com/2015/10/gpu-programming-in-haskell-using-gpipe_21.html) that sort of talks about it, but does not go into detail explaining what I assume is obvious.

```
BufferColor (Color c (ColorElement c)) h ~ b, h ~ HostFormat b
```

So what I know:

- there is an instance of `BufferFormat` for `b`
- `BufferFormat` class has an associated type `HostFormat`
- `h ~ HostFormat b` tells me that `h` must be that `HostFormat` for a given `b` ?
- `h ~ b` this tells me that h and b must be the same type ?

But when I look at the [instances](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GPipe-2.2.4/docs/Graphics-GPipe-Buffer.html#t:BufferFormat) of `BufferFormat b` I don't think there is any such instance that would have `b` equal to its own`HostFormat b` ? Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `BufferColor (Color c (ColorElement c)) h` what must be equal to `b`, not `h`.

[`BufferColor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GPipe-2.2.4/docs/Graphics-GPipe-Buffer.html#t:BufferColor) is a two-argument [type family](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=type%20families#extension-TypeFamilies). Type families behave a bit like functions at the type level. You put types in, and receive another type in return.

And "type family application" has higher precedence than the type equality operator `~`.

Comment: Besides following the definitions, another way of exploring the type families provided by a library is to "run" them from ghci, using the `:kind!` command: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html?highlight=kind#ghci-cmd-:kind We can even use it with `(~)` itself, like `:kind! (~)` or or `:kind! ((~) Int)` or `:kind! (Int ~ Int)`.